# MongoDB mongojs node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I'm trying to learn node, mongodb and mongojs and have a newbie question.

My route looks like this ...

```
server.get({path: PATH + '/:author', version: '0.0.1'}, msg.findMsgsByAuthor);
```

My JSON looks like this ...

```
{
    "parentId": "1234",
    "category": 1,
    "author": "George",
    "title": "Threaded Messages",
    "body": "blah blah blah blah",
    "likes": "5",
    "dislikes": "10",
    "inaccurate": "20"
}
```

What I want to do would be simple in SQL -- `select * from msgs where author = 'George'`

How do I do this using mongo/mongojs?

I've tried something like this with no success...

```
msgs.find({author: req.params.author}, function (err, success) { ...}
```

The callback code is

```
exports.findMsgsByAuthor = function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    msgs.find({author: req.params.author}).sort({category: 1}, function (err, success) {
        logit(err, success);
        if (success) {
            res.send(200, success);
            return next();
        }
        return next(err);
    })
};
```

Here are some declarations

```
var msgs = require('../setup').msgs;
var mongojs = require('../setup').mongojs;
var db = require('../setup').db;
```

And setup.js is

```
var config = require('./config');
var connection_string = config.connectionString;
var mongojs = exports.mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = exports.db = mongojs(connection_string, ['msg', 'user']);
var msgs = exports.msgs = db.collection("msgs");
var port = exports.port = config.port;
var ipAddress = exports.ipAddress = config.ipAddress;
```

And lastly, config.json

```
{
    "connectionString":"127.0.0.1:27017/msg",
    "ipAddress":"127.0.0.1",
    "port": "8080"
}
```

When I say the code is not working, I mean that when I test using the Postman Rest Client Chrome plug in I get the following

```
{
    "code": "InternalError",
    "message": "Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24     hex characters"
}
```

When I attempt a GET with

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/msgs/George
```

If I use a similar callback using msgs.findOne, it works as expected

```
 msgs.findOne({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.msgId)}, function (err, success) {...}
```

I think that should be enough code to explain what I'm trying to do

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your callback code?

Comment: You can edit your original post to include the code you added in the comment.  You should also post the code where you declare `msgs`.  As it stands, there's not enough here to really help you.  Have you looked carefully at the [MongoJS docs](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs)?  I'm sure there's enough there to get you started.

Comment: Yes, I've looked at the docs, tried a few things - obviously incorrectly.  I'm still looking at them and trying to understand, but I thought I'd ask here in the meantime.

Comment: You've done a good job including relevent code, but I'm afraid "not working" is the least helpful description of any problem  -- what isn't working? Do you get an error, or simply no result (a blank page or something)? If you replace `req.params.author` with a known-good value, does it work? Is `msgs` in scope when you call `msgs.find`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working in the same office as this guy helps a lot. The problem he was facing was that he had mapped 2 different handlers to a single route. With no distinction between them, his string `George` was being passed to the `mongojs.ObjectId` builder as part of the `findOne` call and that was generating the `Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters` error message. Updating the routes so that they were distinct solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks ... dummy strikes again.